# CreateCompatibleBitmap and CreateDIBSection (Memory DC's)

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, gdi

from what I've read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/04/25/engineering-windows-7-for-graphics-performance.aspx) it seems that most of the Windows GDI functions are accelerated. So for instance a call to `BitBlt` or `AlphaBlend` uses hardware acceleration if available. It also mentions that the contents of a window are kept only in video memory. Now this is all good and true for a **window DC**, but how can I use a **memory DC** that resides in video card memory? And once we've accomplished that how to obtain direct access to the pixels, I think that would involve 1. temporary copying the data to system memory 2. alter the pixel data 3. copy back to video memory.

I've tried two approaches, both allocate system memory as I can see in the task manager...

1. CreateCompatibleBitmap

   ```
   HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
   m_hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
   m_hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, cx, cy);
   ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

   m_hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(m_hDC, m_hBmp);
   ```

   and then call to obtain the bits

   ```
   GetBitmapBits(...)
   ```

   according to various comments this should indeed create the compatible bitmap in video memory, but why can I still see an increase in system memory (even when I don't call `GetBitmapBits`)?
2. CreateDIBSection

   ```
   HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
   m_hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

   BITMAPINFO bmi;
   memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
   bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = cx;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -cy; // top-down
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   m_hBmp = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&m_pBits, NULL, NULL);

   ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

   m_hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(m_hDC, m_hBmp);
   ```

   in this case we receive the pointer to the bits immediately (`m_pBits`) so it's obvious that these reside in system memory...

Or is it a copy that is kept in system memory for both methods? But if I change the bits in system memory a call to `BitBlt` would still have to check/copy from system memory again... not very optimized IMHO.

EDIT: I've also tried creating memory DC's by using the `BeginBufferedPaint` and `GetBufferedPaintBits`. It allocates system memory as well, so in that respect I suppose it's just a wrapper for the above methods but caches the DC's so a next call doesn't necessarily has to recreate a memory DC. See Raymond Chen's [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/20/10166505.aspx).

EDIT #2: I guess the actual question is: *Am I doing the memory DC creation correct in method 1 or 2 to get hardware accelerated GDI operations?* To me it all seems fast, and both methods provide the same speed too, so there's not really a way to check it...

Comment: I thought it always resides in system memory and only gets swapped into video memory when being rendered to screen ...

Comment: So that would mean we cannot create it in video memory and the GDI functions aren't hardware accelerated when working on a memory DC?

Comment: GDI functions for *blitting operations only* are hardware accelerated on Windows 7 exclusively. GDI+ is still software rendered even on Windows 7 and is still way slower. If you are doing anything complex that requires performance the simple answer is don't use GDI. Use OpenGL or DirectX if you want direct access to hardware. GDI was an always will be an abstraction.

Comment: From what I read GDI functions are hardware accelerated on every version of Windows except Vista (due to it's newly introduced driver design). I'm not using GDI+ btw, and wouldn't recommend anyone to use it any longer since it's not hardware accelerated in Win7.

Comment: GDI was deprecated in favor of GDI+ in Windows XP then they brought GDI back but without hardware acceleration in Vista. Then finally they realized the error of their ways in Windows 7. In any case it's still up to the display adapter driver as whether to support MS-GDI or not.

Comment: Additionally, checking if system memory is used is not a valid indicator whether or not something is hardware accelerated graphics. Depending on the graphics chip, and even the driver, texture data is stored or backed up in system memory (e.g. default behaviour for OpenGL). GDI is hardware accelerated as it is, but you don't have actual control over it. If you _need the control_ I agree with AJG85 that you should use a graphics API instead.

Comment: "As a consequence the BitBlt API was hardware accelerated and most other GDI operations were not." 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct2d/comparing-direct2d-and-gdi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory DCs are not created on a device. They are designed to put GDI output into memory.

From [Memory Device Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> To enable applications to place output in memory rather than sending
>   it to an actual device, use a special device context for bitmap
>   operations called a *memory device context*. A memory DC enables the
>   system to treat a portion of memory as a virtual device.

If you want hardware accelerated 2d graphics, you should consider using [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Aah that makes things clear, and it also says: 

*When displaying a DIB or a DDB created from a DIB on a palette device, you can improve the speed at which the image is drawn by arranging the logical palette to match the layout of the system palette.*

Which makes it clear that `CreateCompatibleBitmap` should be the fastest method, but since my system is run in 32-bit color the `CreateDIBSection` using a 32-bit layout is just as fast (it's the same bitmap format that's created by both functions).

Comment: From my experience with Direct2D vs GDI's performance, I'd not recommend using Direct2D. It is slow, about the same speed as GDI.